# PYTHON: Como contar la cantidad de veces que se repite un par de valores sin importar el orden de los mismos (ejemplo: ['30','56'] y ['56','30']

Tags: python, dataframe, contador

PYTHON: Como contar la cantidad de veces que se repite un par de valores sin importar el orden de los mismos (ejemplo:  ['30','56'] y ['56','30'] y contarlos como el mismo par de valores?? Esto es lo que he intentado y nada...

```
freq_par = df.groupby(['Valor1','Valor2'] and ['Valor2','Valor1']).size()
print(freq_par.sort_values())
```

salida:

```
Valor2  Valor1
25      95        1
30      56        1
31      14        1
50      45        1
56      30        1
        36        1
        94        1
63      89        1
76      89        1
77      45        1
98      71        1
dtype: int64


Dataframe:

    Fecha   Valor1  Valor2
0   21/10/2021  45  50
1   21/10/2021  89  63
2   20/10/2021  71  98
3   20/10/2021  89  76
4   19/10/2021  56  30
5   19/10/2021  36  56
6   18/10/2021  30  56
7   18/10/2021  14  31
8   17/10/2021  95  25
9   17/10/2021  45  77
10  16/10/2021  94  56
```

Comment: y nada.. que???

Comment: No me cuenta el par  30-56 y el 56-30 como el mismo par y los cuenta por separado y lo que necesito es que los cuente como uno solo por lo que el contador debería dar 2... Soy nuevo en esto y estoy aprendiendo python y no se si alguna función o algo me pudiera resolver este asunto...

Comment: podrías colocar tu dataframe??

Comment: [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/493762/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: ya puse un fragmento del dataframe...

Comment: disculpa la demora es que es primera ves que hago una pregunta en este sitio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te recomiendo es ordenar los con la función `sorted(x)` así ya siempre van a estar en el mismo orden, luego lo que puede hacer es recorrer tu lista y guardar en un diccionario, usando como llave el par ordenado y como valor la cantidad de veces que lo encontró

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo simple de cómo se vería

```
l = [[1,2],[3,1],[2,1]]
d = {}
for i in l: 
    s = str(sorted(i)) 
    if s in d: 
        d[s]+=1
    else:
        d[s]=1
print(d) #{'[1, 2]': 2, '[1, 3]': 1}
```

Use la función `str()` para convertir la lista de dos valores en una string y así poder usarlo como llave en el diccionario por que como tal una lista no puede ser usada.
Luego verificamos si la llave está en el diccionario `if s in d` si es así significa que tenemos una nueva coincidencia y hay que incrementar nuestro contador `d[s]+=1` en caso contrario significa que es la primera vez que encontramos esa secuencia de numero asi que agregamos una nueva llave y la asignamos el valor a 1 `d[s]=1`

Comment: Gracias hermano me fuiste de mucha ayuda... crees que se pueda ordenar los resultados ascendente o descendentemente??

Comment: Si usando la función de `sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=reverse)` en este caso tu iterable sería el diccionario con los valores para key depende si quieres ordenar por el par de número o la cantidad que aparecen sería usando `lamba x:x[0]`  o `lamba x:x[1]` respectivamente y el reverse por defecto es false para ascendente o puedes enviar un true para descendente